# How did Peter rise so high?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-amazing-spider-man-2

*The Amazing Spider-Man 2* starts with a scene where Peter is shown falling down from a great height. He couldn't rise so high with his webs. How did he do that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### He's freefalling after launching himself at the top of a swing.

Clearly, as we see from later shots he has the ability to launch himself into the air (unsupported by webs) at the top of a swing **much** higher than the buildings around him that form anchor points for the webs.

As he reaches the top of the swing he just **let's go** of the web and continues upwards based on momentum until such time as gravity takes over again.